# Videos of Salesforce implementations?

Tags: design

One thing I found really helpful was when a friend walked me through his company's implementation of salesforce.  While Salesforce is highly customizable, that's only any good if you take the time to customize your salesforce.  That can be a little bit daunting, trying to think of how to structure your the open canvas that is your salesforce.

Is anyone aware of video walkthroughs where people have recorded walkthroughs of their salesforce implementations?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this might help you, but salesforce.com has [Salesforce TV](http://www.salesforce.com/video/). I didn't find any specific videos elsewhere, but you have to remember that salesforce.com is indeed an open canvas; this is both a blessing and a curse. What works for other people might not work for you, and what others failed at might be the perfect idea for your business process. When I get some time, I might make some tutorials based on my experience and knowledge of salesforce.com on how to implement various processes.